# How add payment method to a private blockchain

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps

I have a question about private blokchain:

I like to develop an Dapp in my own private blockchain. but i like to add payment method : i means,  how users account pay (with stripe,..) and load his balance (our local ICO ) in our local private blockchain.

We don't like using the ethreum public blockchain, to save the transaction fees ( gas ).

Comment: You will need to specify your question more precisely otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: @ivicaa it's more clear now ?

Comment: Does stripe has support for ether?

Comment: @ivicaa, i means how i can add payment methods to my private blockchain.

Comment: A private blockchain is like a distributed database. You can use a payment processor like any other webapp, having a private blockchain doesn't make it different from the regular webapp.

Comment: @Ismael but how i do this ? if some one pay with his credit card , how i save it to blockchain ???

Comment: @Koceilalounici How will you do it if you were using a database? You will add the payment to the customer credit. With a private blockchain you do the same, you add to the customer credit, it can be mintings tokens in a contract or sending them ethers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read up on how dapps and permissioned chains work first.

Comment: i means how i can add payment methods to my private blockchain.